# React protected component's redux state is reset before thunk promise resolves

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using the MERN stack and I have a [component](https://github.com/Hasnain123Raza/ASCII-Craft-Client/tree/master/src/areas/Art/scenes/Create) that will create resources to store on the database. This component has an associated [redux slice](https://github.com/Hasnain123Raza/ASCII-Craft-Client/blob/master/src/areas/Art/scenes/Create/services/artCreateSlice/index.js) to store its state. The state includes the status of the request made to the server for posting the resource to create.

When React first executes, the main display [component](https://github.com/Hasnain123Raza/ASCII-Craft-Client/tree/master/src/components/Main) uses a [redux-thunk](https://github.com/Hasnain123Raza/ASCII-Craft-Client/tree/master/src/services/loaderSlice) to load some important resources. Currently, it loads the authentication status of the user in a [redux slice](https://github.com/Hasnain123Raza/ASCII-Craft-Client/tree/master/src/services/authenticatedSlice). When the person logs in or logs out, this authentication status is changed.

When a user loses their authentication status while already having loaded up a protected component, the server denies access to protected resources and allows the client to sync its authentication status. For example, the user logs in and goes to the protected component that creates resources. The user then logs out on a different tab. Now, the client still believes the user is authenticated but the server knows they are not. If the client makes a request to create a new resource, the server will reject it and the client will sync its authentication status with the server.

The problem I am facing is in a [redux-thunk](https://github.com/Hasnain123Raza/ASCII-Craft-Client/blob/master/src/areas/Art/scenes/Create/services/artCreateSlice/index.js) inside the redux slice that is associated with the protected component. If the server rejects the create request because the user is unauthenticated, the thunk dispatches an action to update the authentication status of the user.

When the authentication status of the user changes, a [ProtectedRoute](https://github.com/Hasnain123Raza/ASCII-Craft-Client/blob/master/src/components/ProtectedRoute/index.js) component immediately unmounts the protected components and mounts the login component ([here](https://github.com/Hasnain123Raza/ASCII-Craft-Client/blob/master/src/areas/Art/index.js)). Upon being unmounted, the protected component dispatches an action to reset its redux state.

Now, all of this happens as the action to reset authentication has been dispatched. The redux-thunk promise resolves after this and a reducer changes the protected component's redux state. This makes the reset state action useless.

```
if (data.success) {
  return data;
} else {
  if (data.error.unauthenticated) {
    // resetAuthentication action causes the protected component
    // to unmount which causes it to reset associated redux state.
    dispatch(resetAuthentication());
  }
  // thunk resolves and changes the redux state.
  return rejectWithValue();

  // PROBLEM: The thunk resolves after the resetAuthentication action has caused
  // the protected component to reset. After it is resolved, the state is changed
  // again making the reset useless.
}
```

**Essentially this happens:**

- Client makes a request to protected resources
- Server rejects it because the client is not authenticated and gives the client the opportunity to sync the authentication status
- Client syncs the authentication status causing the user to move away from the protected component, which causes its state to reset because of unmounting
- Client redux-thunk dealing with the create request resolves and rejects causing a change to the protected component's redux state
- Protected component's reset action on unmount becomes useless

For my application, this means that the next time user opens the protected component (after having logged in), they can see the effects of a rejected create request such as the button for creating resources appearing as a red *Retry* instead of a green *Create*.

I want protected resources to be able to reset their state properly but authentication failure causes them to be unmounted by the ProtectedRoute component. I want to find a way that solves this issue with minimal noise and extra boilerplate code for future protected resources.

**Solutions I think would work:**

- Modify my ProtectedRoute component to give the redirect URL to the protected component so that the protected component can redirect after the thunk promise has resolved and the state will not be touched after resetting on unmount (Requires me to change ProtectedRoute implementation from something that I find everywhere. Introduces boilerplate code in protected components).

I also believe there might be a fundamental issue in the way I have organized components and their associated redux slices. Please also suggest best practices for the situation as a whole.

Comment: Can you explain "This makes the reset state action useless."? why does the order of execution matter?

Comment: @thedude The reset state action is supposed to reset the redux state back to the initial state. If it runs before the thunk resolves, the state is changed and is not really back to the initial state. This means my goal of resetting the state so that when the user navigates back to the component is not met and the user will see artifacts from the thunk's resolution such as a retry button instead of a create button.

Comment: please explain "the state is changed and is not really back to the initial state". why is it not back to the initial state if you have an action the resets the state?

Comment: @thedude It gets back to the initial state when the reset action is dispatched. However, because the thunk promise resolves after the reset has been dispatched, the reducer that is triggered then changes the state. So the state is being changed after it has been reset. This means the state isn't back to its initial state anymore.

Comment: can you explain in what way the state changes when the promise is rejected? Please give a concrete example

Comment: My initial state for the protected component has a string value called "postCreateArtRequestStatus" which can be "idle", "pending", "rejected",  or "fulfilled". Its value is modified by the thunk promise when it resolves and the value reflects the status of the post request that the client sends to the server to create and store a resource on the database. In the scenario discussed in the OP, after the reset action is dispatched and the state is reset, the thunk promise resolves and "postCreateArtRequestStatus" changes to "rejected". This means the state is no longer its initial value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest a few possible approaches for your issue:

1. signal that state update should be ignored with a different value: You can provide a different value to `rejectWithValue` such that your reducer can ignore the update if this value is provided. So in your reducer you could do something like:

```
if (data.error.unauthenticated) {
    dispatch(resetAuthentication());
    return rejectWithValue('cancelUpdate');
} else {
    return rejectWithValue();
}
```

and in the reducer:

```
...
.addCase(postCreateArt.rejected, (state, action) => {
    if (!action.payload === 'cancelUpdate') {
        state.postCreateArtRequestStatus = "rejected";
    }
})
```

2. One drawback with this approach is that it will have to be implemented for each API you use. Instead of using `fetch` directly you could have a generic `fetchApi` thunk that all your API actions would use. This thunk could handle the `unauthenticated` flow in a central place.